# How to make UIProgressBar programmatically in swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uiprogressbar

I want to make UIProgressBar programmatically in swift?

what is wrong in this code?

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .Bar)
        progressView.center = self.view.center
        progressView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,20)
        progressView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        progressView.setProgress(0.5, animated: false)
        self.view.addSubview(progressView)
 }
```

Comment: You said `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, but then didn't add any constraints. Just add constraints to dictate where you want this. If you look at the view debugger, I bet this view is not where you expect it to be...

Comment: thank you @Rob , it is working fine.

Answer (score 11):

```swift
let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .Bar)
progressView.center = view.center
progressView.setProgress(0.5, animated: true)
progressView.trackTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
progressView.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
view.addSubview(progressView)
```

you need to do this type code and you can't need to set frame .

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Add subview of your progressView
2. Set up the constraints, since you make translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5:

```
let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .bar)
progressView.center = view.center
progressView.setProgress(0.5, animated: true)
progressView.trackTintColor = .lightGray
progressView.tintColor = .blue
view.addSubview(progressView)
```